# Can dropping a partition automatically release space in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning

Will the following SQL command release space automatically while dropping that partition?

```
      Alter table abc Drop partition p1;
```

Comment: yes this will release the space used by the partition, making it available to the database, not to the OS

Comment: A partition drop drops the underlying segment (or segments, if subpartitioned). This marks extents formerly allocated to this segment and any dependent partitioned objects (corresponding partition of any locally partitioned index segments and LOB segments) as unused, making them available within the tablespace for reuse by another object assigned to the same tablespace. It does not however return this space to the underlying storage system, as that would require shrinking the tablespace itself.